# Oozie Kill Node reached but job status is still running

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

Submitted a job through Oozie workflow.  I have DECISION node which invokes a KILL node.  The KILL node is reached, however Oozie Web Console is still showing the status of the job as RUNNING.

When I look at the job detail screen, I see the action name for the kill-node, status OK.

```
<decision name="should-do_something">
      <switch>
          <case to="action_node">
              ${1 eq 0}
          </case>
          <default to="failed"/>
      </switch>
  </decision>

  <kill name="failed">
    <message>here is my msg </message>  
  </kill>
```

Also when I do `hadoop job -list` it reports that there are no jobs...

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that I had a syntax error in the message section.  After fixing the syntax error it worked.  Not sure why a syntax error would effect the oozie workflow manager, etc.